# Typed projection with Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to define a Type on the query side to map my join so that I can avoid returning a tuple of values that I have to manually apply to my projection case class post query.

Given a relationship like:

```
case class Parent(id: Int, name: String, extra: String)

class ParentTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Parent](tag, "parent") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def extra = column[String]("extra")
  def * = (id, name, extra) <> (Parent.tupled, Parent.unapply)
}

val parents = TableQuery[ParentTable]

case class Child(id: Int, parentId: Int, name: String, extra:  String)

class ChildTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Child](tag, "child") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def parentId = column[Int]("parent_id")
  def parent = foreignKey("parent_fk", parentId, parents)(_.id)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def extra = column[String]("extra")
  def * = (id, parentId, name, extra) <> (Child.tupled, Child.unapply)
}
val children = TableQuery[ChildTable]
```

I want to project into a case class like:

```
  case class ChildWithParentName(id: Int, name: String, parentName: String)
```

The join and projection looks like:

```
val q = for {
  c <- children
  p <- parents if c.parentId === p.id
} yield (c.id,c.name,p.name)
```

I put this in a function and allow `children` and `parents` to be parameterized. The function doesn't run the query, because sometimes I want `.result` and sometimes I want `.result.headOption`, so my function signature is:

```
Query[(Rep[Int], Rep[String], Rep[String]), (Int, String, String), Seq]
```

I would like to create a Type on the Query side with a shape something like:

```
class ChildParentProjection(val id: Rep[Int], 
                            val name: Rep[String], 
                            val parentName[String])
```

so that I could get a function signature like:

```
Query[ChildParentProjection, ChildWithParentName, Seq]
```

Is that possible in slick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why you would like to use the class `ChildParentProjection`.
if you want to return a `Seq[ChildWithParentName]` when executing `result` on the query, you'll have to map the tuple resulting from your monadic join to the `ChildWithParentName` class like this :

```
val q = for {
c <- children
p <- parents if c.parentId === p.id
} yield (c.id,c.name,p.name) <> (ChildWithParentName.tupled,ChildWithParentName.unapply)
```

I wish I have understood your question

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware that `<>` could be applied at the query level. The resulting `MappedProjection` is exactly what I wanted to accomplish and so much simpler than what I had imagined I needed to do, i.e. no `ChildParentProjection` required. One additional question though: Before `q` could easily be used in a `sortBy`, but i can't seem to extract either the tuple or `ChildWithParentName from `MappedProjection`